# force filebeat to log to a file

Tags: systemd, elasticsearch

Using filebeat-8.7.1, I have it configured to push several sources to a remote elastisearch. I cannot get it to log its own logging to a local file `/var/log/filebeat/filebeat.log`, and I cannot prevent it from dumping its logs into `/var/log/syslog` (which is also going to elastisearch).

The relevant configuration from `/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml`:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: filestream
  id: rsc-server
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/rstudio/rstudio-connect/rstudio*.log
  fields:
    log_type: rsc_server
- type: filestream
  enabled: true
  ignore_older: 5m
  id: rsc-jobs
  paths:
    - /srv/R/RSC/jobs/[0-9]*/*/*
  fields:
    log_type: rsc
filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false
setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1
setup.kibana:
  host: "http://my.elasti.host:30002"
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["http://my.elasti.host:30003"]
  allow_older_versions: true
  username: "myuser"
  password: "mypass"
processors:
  - add_host_metadata:
      when.not.contains.tags: forwarded
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
  - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~
logging:
  - level: warning
  - to_syslog: false
  - to_stderr: false
  - json: true
  - files:
    - path: /var/log/filebeat
    - name: filebeat
    - keepfile: 3
    - permissions: 0644
```

And from the `/etc/filebeat/modules.d/` directory, the resulting enabled configs are:

```
# Module: nginx
# Docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/filebeat-module-nginx.html
- module: nginx
  # Access logs
  access:
    enabled: true
    # Set custom paths for the log files. If left empty,
    # Filebeat will choose the paths depending on your OS.
    #var.paths:
  # Error logs
  error:
    enabled: true
    # Set custom paths for the log files. If left empty,
    # Filebeat will choose the paths depending on your OS.
    #var.paths:
  # Ingress-nginx controller logs. This is disabled by default. It could be used in Kubernetes environments to parse ingress-nginx logs
  ingress_controller:
    enabled: false
    # Set custom paths for the log files. If left empty,
    # Filebeat will choose the paths depending on your OS.
    #var.paths:
# Module: redis
# Docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/filebeat-module-redis.html
- module: redis
  # Main logs
  log:
    enabled: true
    # Set custom paths for the log files. If left empty,
    # Filebeat will choose the paths depending on your OS.
    #var.paths: ["/var/log/redis/redis-server.log*"]
  # Slow logs, retrieved via the Redis API (SLOWLOG)
  slowlog:
    enabled: false
    # The Redis hosts to connect to.
    #var.hosts: ["localhost:6379"]
    # Optional, the password to use when connecting to Redis.
    #var.password:
# Module: system
# Docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/filebeat-module-system.html
- module: system
  # Syslog
  syslog:
    enabled: true
    # Set custom paths for the log files. If left empty,
    # Filebeat will choose the paths depending on your OS.
    #var.paths:
  # Authorization logs
  auth:
    enabled: true
    # Set custom paths for the log files. If left empty,
    # Filebeat will choose the paths depending on your OS.
    #var.paths:
```

I *believe* that the system module use of `syslog` is to *pull from* `/var/log/syslog`, not push to it. (And when I disable that module, the behavior does not change.)

How do I fix the `logging.*` section to send logs to `/var/log/filebeat/`, and how to I prevent it from sending to syslog and `/var/log/syslog`?

(This is on an ubuntu-22.04 VM.)

---

*Edit*: `/lib/systemd/system/filebeat.service` has an empty `BEAT_LOG_OPTS` arg (this is the default file, not edited by me):

```
[Unit]
Description=Filebeat sends log files to Logstash or directly to Elasticsearch.
Documentation=https://www.elastic.co/beats/filebeat
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
[Service]
UMask=0027
Environment="GODEBUG='madvdontneed=1'"
Environment="BEAT_LOG_OPTS="
Environment="BEAT_CONFIG_OPTS=-c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml"
Environment="BEAT_PATH_OPTS=--path.home /usr/share/filebeat --path.config /etc/filebeat --path.data /var/lib/filebeat --path.logs /var/log/filebeat"
ExecStart=/usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat --environment systemd $BEAT_LOG_OPTS $BEAT_CONFIG_OPTS $BEAT_PATH_OPTS
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

With a reload (and no change in performance):

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl restart filebeat.service
# systemctl status filebeat.service

● filebeat.service - Filebeat sends log files to Logstash or directly to Elasticsearch.
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/filebeat.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-05-04 14:49:12 UTC; 20s ago
       Docs: https://www.elastic.co/beats/filebeat
   Main PID: 2080223 (filebeat)
      Tasks: 25 (limit: 76964)
     Memory: 114.4M
        CPU: 5.315s
     CGroup: /system.slice/filebeat.service
             └─2080223 /usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat --environment systemd -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml --path.home /usr/share/filebeat --path.config /etc/filebeat --path.data /var/lib/filebeat --path.logs /var/log/filebeat
```

The process is running as root, and the `/var/log/filebeat` directory is owned by root with normal perms:

```
# ps faxu | grep [/]filebeat
root     2080223  9.4  0.1 2635592 169112 ?      Ssl  14:49   0:36 /usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat --environment systemd -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml --path.home /usr/share/filebeat --path.config /etc/filebeat --path.data /var/lib/filebeat --path.logs /var/log/filebeat

# ll -d /var/log/filebeat
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May  4 12:54 /var/log/filebeat/
# ll  /var/log/filebeat
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 May  4 12:54 ./
drwxr-xr-x 18 root syslog 4096 May  4 12:54 ../
```

I see `--environment systemd` that per [filebeat command-line-options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/command-line-options.html) means

> *If systemd or container is specified, Filebeat will log to stdout and stderr by default.*

This suggests that logging is going to `/var/log/syslog` due to the way `systemd` is handling stdout/stderr from the process. That seems like progress, but we still don't have logging going to `/var/log/filebeat/`, which is ultimately where both stdout/stderr should be going (which would resolve the problem of logging to `/var/log/syslog`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the post
[Filebeat refuses to log to file](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-refuses-to-log-to-file-7-0-1/181846).

The explanation there, quoted from the
[release notes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/current/release-notes-7.0.0.html)
is:

> On systems with systemd, the Beats log is now written to journald by default rather than file. To revert this behaviour override BEAT_LOG_OPTS with an empty value

And the solution itself you may be able to adapt to your
environment :

> To override these variables, create a drop-in unit file in the
> /etc/systemd/system/filebeat.service.d directory.
>
> To use [the logging] settings from the Filebeat file, empty the
> environment variable. For example:
>
> ```
> [Service]
> Environment="BEAT_LOG_OPTS="
> ```
>
> To apply your changes, reload the systemd configuration and restart
> the service:
>
> ```
> systemctl daemon-reload
> systemctl restart filebeat
> ```
>
> It is recommended that you use a configuration management tool to
> include drop-in unit files. If you need to add a drop-in manually, use
> systemctl edit filebeat.service .
>
> Reference for the command line of filebeat to understand what the unit
> file does and what it can do:
> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.0/command-line-options.html#global-flags
> 4
>
> To see the default filebeat unit file that came with the installation
> do:
>
> ```
> systemctl status filebeat
> ```
>
> and check the content of the unit file. (The path to the unit file is
> in the output of the above command.)

Comment: Thank you harrymc. I had seen notes about the `BEAT_LOT_OPTS=` and had confirmed it before posting the question. I edited the question to include that fact.

Comment: harrymc, while editing the question to expand on your answer, I realized that `--environment systemd` is sending output to stdout/stderr, which I believe `systemd` is then dumping to `/var/log/syslog`. I believe that if we can resolve why filebeat is not logging to `/var/log/filebeat/`, the syslog component should self-resolve.

Comment: I don't have your environment, so I need to go by documentation. According to [this post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-7-10-1-cannot-write-to-var-log-filebeat/262419) you should remove `--environment` from `filebeat.service`.

Answer (score 0):

harrymc helped identify the culprit, here are some final steps plus an alternative workaround.

The issue with filebeat logging to `/var/log/syslog` was with `systemd` services, not filebeat itself: the use of `--environment systemd` on the filebeat command line (which is the *default* on ubuntu, perhaps part of the problem) is causing filebeat to force logging to stdout. This is counter to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/command-line-options.html#global-flags) suggesting that this bypass only occurs when logging is not otherwise defined:

```
 -environment
    For logging purposes, specifies the environment that Filebeat is
    running in. This setting is used to select a default log output
    when no log output is configured. Supported values are: systemd,
    container, macos_service, and windows_service. If systemd or
    container is specified, Filebeat will log to stdout and stderr
    by default.
```

## Option 1: remove `--environment systemd`

Run `systemctl edit filebeat.service`, and remove the command-line arguments from `ExecStart` (after first clearing that variable). The edited text should contain

```
### /lib/systemd/system/filebeat.service
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat $BEAT_LOG_OPTS $BEAT_CONFIG_OPTS $BEAT_PATH_OPTS
```

The first *empty* `ExecStart=` is intentional: without it, systemd will complain about `Service has more than one ExecStart= setting`.

By doing this, we now see `/var/log/filebeat/filebeat-20230504.ndjson`.

Many thanks to @user1686 for helping me to find the resolution for multiple `ExecStart=` settings.

## Option 2: redirect stdout/stderr via systemd

Another option is to keep filebeat dumping to its stdout/stderr and using its internal mechanisms for redirecting to files. (If you made the change to `/lib/systemd/system/filebeat.service` in option 1, then *undo that change* for this option.)

Call `systemctl edit filebeat.service` and include this,

```
[Service]
StandardOutput=file:/var/log/filebeat/filebeat_stdout.log
StandardError=file:/var/log/filebeat/filebeat_stderr.log
```

(which is stored within `/etc/systemd/system/filebeat.service.d/override.conf`). Then restart the service, we now see `/var/log/filebeat/filebeat_stdout.log` (and `_stderr`).

Comment: You could use `systemctl edit` for both options, surely.

Comment: @user1686, it did not work for me: when changing `ExecStart` via `systemctl edit`, when I reloaded, systemd complained with `Service has more than one ExecStart= setting`. Is there a way to override a value that is not _additive_?

Comment: Yes, primarily `systemctl edit --full` which puts the _entire_ unit file in `/etc`. But if you prefer service.d/ style, then an empty "`ExecStart=`" setting will have the effect of clearing the entire list for most multivalued options (except for dependencies – doesn't work for Wants/After/&c), after which you can set the new ExecStart value again.

Comment: I see. In more research from your suggestion, I think a more "reduced" solution would be akin to https://askubuntu.com/a/659268, first clearing then re-setting `ExecStart`. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: But, that aside, the docs of `--environment` say "…when no log output is configured", so why would it _force_ logging to stdout after you've explicitly configured logging to a file – shouldn't that be considered a bug in the service?

Comment: I think it does.